# Allow tag wiki to be referenced in duplicate close vote

Tags: feature-request

Several tags, namely PHP and javascript, have extensive tag wiki entries, complete with FAQ answers and links to relevant documentation.

If a user asks a question that has been addressed many, many times, we can choose to close it and link some other question as the duplicate. Sometimes, however, there are not any good duplicates to point at because they were also bad questions that could be answered via the documentation, or are addressed on the tag wiki. I've seen questions that have duplicate close reasons pointing at a question that was closed as a duplicate of a question that was closed as off topic.

I propose that we should be able to use the tag wiki as the common reference point when closing FAQ-type questions. There does not seem to be [much appreciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php) of [reference-type answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) (and they are only effective if you know about them), so this seems like the most simple and clean way to index many, many duplicate/poorly researched questions into a single, authoritative source.

In summary,

**The problem** many, many duplications of extremely common questions with no single, authoritative, centralized place to link them to that everyone is aware of

**The proposed solution** Link to the tag wiki when closing as a duplicate

---

Good reference thread on MetaMeta with a different approach: [Duplicates Mark II, Canonicals, more aggressive duplicate prevention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230507/duplicates-mark-ii-canonicals-more-aggressive-duplicate-prevention)

Answer (score 5):

I don't find the tag wiki's easily searchable or reference-able and maybe it's just a personal gripe but I think there's too much information in some of them.  While it may be quality material the likes of the content in the *php* wiki should really be broken down into individual posts (community wiki) each of which addressing the **specific** areas that don't already have an adopted canonical source on SO.

Content provided via the normal Q&A mechanism is far easier to read and digest.  I'd also imagine - purely assumption - that it's better indexed that way as well, it's my understanding that the majority of queries are phrased as questions anyway?

If the the wiki *was* to be used as a reference can we at least have a way of jumping to a specific point - ***i.e.*** put anchors / url-fragments on header tags in the markup (or something to that effect).

Comment: I agree with the need for anchors, but the trouble I see with reference CW questions is that you have to know they exist for them to be useful. Everyone already knows the tag wikis exist.

Comment: Traditional "mediaWiki" sites have special markup that allow you to include sections of other pages / posts on the site so you don't have to duplicate content.  There's no reason why the tag-wiki's couldn't be used as a single index point for all the other references/sources - maybe even including some kind of "onebox" thing-a-majig?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with that is the users don't read. If they would have read, they'd reach their answer eventually (because, well, we're talking about questions that are answered in the Tag Wiki).

Which means that even if you start closing questions as duplicates of tag wikis, people will still ask more questions, simply because the tag wiki is "Pfft, this is too long for me to read now, GIMME ANSWERS!".

So while I fully support your way of thinking, I don't think this is the right solution for the problem. The solution is a better process of finding and marking duplicate questions, incentivising and other fun stuff to allow for making duplicate marking much easier.

For more information, see my meta.stackexchange post: [Duplicates Mark II, Canonicals, more aggressive duplicate prevention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230507/duplicates-mkii-canonicals-more-aggressive-duplicate-prevention)

Comment: To be fair, it probably doesn't occur to most users to read the extended tag wiki to find the answer to their problem. That is far from an intuitive action.