# Let's not strive to make all canonical questions a pain to make

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, canonical

I've noticed a rather disturbing trend revolving around canonical questions. It seems as though many people tend to think that canonical questions should be community wiki, that they should not award anyone rep.

## Why?

- Why shouldn't I get rep on a Q&A I worked on for a week?
- Why shouldn't I get the badges?
- Why would I actually take the time to make a canonical answer if I know it's not going to be accepted well, I'm going to get much headaches and eventually, no reward from it?

## STAHP

This attitude is annoying and disturbing. If I work on a canonical and post it, I deserve all the rep on it.

Now, I don't mind the rep, or the badges. I've over 50k, I'm past that, and so are many of the people who write canonicals. But this whole overhead and negativity around it really sucks the juice out of us.

Yeah, we get rep for our excellent question and answer. **DEAL WITH IT**.

This is a discussion more than anything else, (which I don't tend to do on meta, because I usually try to come up with solutions to every problem I raise). But I think the problem in this case is not systematic ot programmatic, but cultural and behavioral.

What do you think we should do? We've already a blog post saying it's OK, it's been discussed several times and we've reached the same conclusion: *We want canonicals*, so why must every canonical open and close 5 times and then be made CW or dissociated from the OP's account?

<sub>I keep saying "I" in this question, but I actually mean anyone who's posting/thinking of posting a canonical question and answer pair</sub>

Comment: Everyone can do as he likes. You don't have to make your posts CW. And what others do is their own concern. There is nothing **we** should do here.

Comment: @juergend: Like I said, this isn't a system problem. It's a community behavioral problem that needs addressing. Do we, or do we not want canonical questions on the site? Because if we do, we're sure not doing enough to encourage them.

Comment: I don't get your point - is there anyone forcing you to do this or what is the problem if someone wants to make his own post CW? Do you want people to stop that?

Comment: @juergend He is working with a group of people, so there is a "we" involved, and some of them apply pressure for CW to be applied to all canonical questions.

Comment: I don't know what tags you have tried to do this for, but my experience writing C++ canonical questions/answers has been quite positive. There's the odd annoying user, but I received mostly upvotes and encouraging comments. Other users had similar experiences. The only reason I don't do it more often is that I have time for other things.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Nearly all of the canonicals on the [tag:php] tag suffered from these "birth pains".

Comment: Related on MSE: [Encourage the posting of Canonical Questions by making “Answer Your Own Question” posts Community Wiki automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204214)

Comment: I'd rather have someone gain 10k rep from a canonical Q/A pair of a FAQ than 100 others gaining even more rep by answering the same question thousands of times...

Comment: Is it true that mods are able to CW one of my posts if they want to? Isn't that just unfair and unreasonable?

Comment: Mods can CW your post at will, but will generally not do so without an actual request from the author.

Comment: Hmm wow. Not that I'm likely to end up with a CW style post, but still.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Mods can also delete your posts if they want to. Would that be unfair and unreasonable as well? Keep in mind mods generally don't use their powers to annoy the users...

Comment: @l4mpi good point I've taken that the wrong way. Of course they can...

Comment: Don't forget the peer pressure when some 300k user makes some overall addings to your post and tells you to change it to CW.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: If it's one 300k user, I don't mind that much. If it's 5 different users, I'll start thinking about it.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Well *you*... you have 55k ...

Comment: Why the hell would you care about someone complaining **over the internet**? It really doesn't matter who you are and how much rep you have. The first rule of the internet is to never take heaters' hate seriously. So what if he wants? If you want to edit, edit. If you don't want to, don't. Why do I need to change myself (or my thoughts) because you asked me to?

Comment: @SecondRikudo: because that is how the whole social mechanism behind intimidation and bullying works. The artificial barrier of it being on the internet doesn't mean anything to the initial feelings this creates. "Oh there is some big reputable guy asking me to do something, he is probably right". In this specific case the message perceived by most is likely "I (with my superior reputation and thus knowledge) edited the question to make it much better, now I think you don't deserve the reputation anymore for making the initial effort of creating one" and very few will even question this.

Answer (score 27):

The reason you would mark the answer as Community Wiki, for a canonical question, is not to stop the author from earning reputation, but rather to encourage and enable the community to edit the post, and to change its content with edits, instead of treating the post as content owned by the original author.

If you don't want to do that with your answer, there is no reason that you need to mark it as CW.  If you want your answer to be *your* answer and not something that anyone can come along and rewrite to change its content, then that's entirely fine.

Next we need to ask ourselves why CW posts don't award rep.  It's not there to punish people for writing a canonical question.  It doesn't award rep because *the content is not representing the contributions of just that one user*.  In a CW answer, a ton of people *besides* the author have (in theory) made significant contributions, and not just to the presentation of the content, but to the content itself.  There's no real good way of trying to distribute the rep earned among the users (people have suggested this, but it's too open to abuse) so the compromise is to simply award none at all.

As for the badges, the original author of a CW post *does* get any badges that the post would get.

As for canonical posts simply being a headache, that's not simply a matter of the community being bad, it's because *writing canonical posts is very hard*.  It is the inherent difficulty of writing really good canonical questions, especially in the format of SO, that creates headaches for everyone involved.

Comment: Yes, but in reality, it's eventually a mod or some other party marking it as CW because the OP feels bad about all of the negativity he gets (or because the post was flagged and the mod agrees with it; which is rarer). OP gets badges for CW posts, but not for posts that got dissociated from him, which also happened several times. And no, writing a canonical is great experience. It's the closing and reopening several times after that makes it a "headache".

Comment: Also, not to mention that CW was made to allow low reputation users to make edits easily before suggested edits were introduced. So even if the CW status represents a post which is edited by the community, there's little merit to it nowdays (fact, the automatic CW status was disabled everywhere).

Comment: @SecondRikudo I find it quite rare for mods to CW a canonical post.  Sometimes there are comments saying that the post should be CW, and authors give in an CW their post.  Other times enough other users are editing the posts that they automatically get CW-ed through edits.  If your canonical question is being closed, odds are you wrote a great answer to an awful question.  You can't just write a tutorial on Fooing the Baz and then have a question that is, "How do I Foo the Baz?"  That's a *terrible* question that *should* be closed.  Writing a good canonical *question* is *very* hard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: @SecondRikudo That's true to a point, although it's important to keep in mind that suggested edits are really there to improve the *presentation* of a post, not to edit its *content*.  By CW-ing a post you allow 100-2000 rep users to update the *content*, not just the *presentation*.

Comment: @SecondRikudo The post itself, in its original revision, stated, "This is also a Community Wiki, so everyone is invited to participate in maintaining it."  Pretty sure that he flagged the post *himself* for it to be CW.  It's not like a mod swooped in and made a post CW when the author clearly didn't want the post's content to be edited by others.  It also doesn't really match well with the Q/A format of the site.  It's not really a question at all, and it doesn't really have an answer (it can't, what without any question).  That it generates headaches is unsurprising.

Comment: The story is a bit more complicated than that. HamZa worked very hard on that post. He didn't originally mean it to become like it is today, that's the end point. It wasn't unwillingly, but IIRC he was pressured into making it CW.

Comment: @SecondRikudo There are a whole mess of problems with that post.  As I said, it's not even a question; it doesn't have an answer.  The question meets all sorts of guidelines for closure.  To me that looks like something that just isn't well suited for an SO question to begin with.

Comment: @Servy Visit the regex tag for a few hours and you'll see the mess there is there. Anyways I ranted about it [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868). I asked a mod to make it CW to prevent all arguments against me about gained rep. Also I felt that it's a bit unfair to the people who helped me (morally and technically). I'm happy with the results, it's live and working great. Now if only Robert unlocked it so that we could split up the answer. It would have been an extra bonus if I gained rep after a few weeks of preparation.

Comment: @HamZa While I don't really touch the regex tag, I'm quite certain it's a mess.  Really though, what you posted wasn't a canonical question.  It was a link to a whole bunch of *other* canonical questions.  While that's not necessarily a bad thing in general, it's *not* actually a canonical question, and the Q/A model of the site simply isn't well suited to that type of content.  That makes it a poor example *for the purposes of this particular meta post*.

Comment: The issue here is not about CW vs not CW @Servy. It's about why the post gets CWed, if it's because you want it CWed for people to add info to it, great, go ahead. If it's because "I don't want the bunch of rep envy vultures to harrass me", then we've got a problem.

Comment: @SecondRikudo And yet you need to realize that CW is not a "you can't fault me for any problems with this post anymore" flag either.  While some people may simply be upset at someone else getting rep, most of the complaints that I see on questions like this are legitimate, because writing quality canonical questions is simply *hard*.  At the end of the day, if its your intention to write a post that you want tens of thousands of people to be reading, you need to be prepared to deal with some negative feedback and people bitching about your post.  If you can't deal with that, don't post it.

Comment: @Servy: I don't mind negative feedback *on my post*, or people bitching *about my post*. I mind that people bitch about me getting credit for something I deserve, and to deal with that, most people simply "alright whatever, I'll just CW it".

Comment: @SecondRikudo And if they feel that the rep is worth less to them than dealing with the comments, that's their choice to make.  Most of the people qualified to write these really good canonical questions don't really need any more rep anyway.  *They* often don't see the need to earn the rep of the canonical post, even if *you* think they should get it.

Comment: @Servy: I don't think that they should get it. I think that they should decide for themselves, and not because you or I decided it for them. That's all.

Comment: "The reason you would mark the answer as Community Wiki... is... to encourage and enable the community to edit the post.... There's no real good way of trying to distribute the rep earned among the users... so the compromise is to simply award none at all." Pretty succinct critique of the reputation system generally, that. It claims to be an incentive system, but is utterly incapable of incentivizing practically anything good, and actively incentivizes a lot of bad things. "Let's encourage people to edit! By... not giving them reputation in case there's bickering!"

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If you are interested in learning more about that topic, I'd suggest looking into SO's brief"documentation" feature (which, granted, is hard to search for on meta as the word is often referring to a site's official documentation and not the ill fated SO feature).  It involved having wiki-style articles that could be edited by anyone, and that attempted to split up the rep earned among all of the contributors.  It turned out horribly, one of the many problems being people going around making trivial or even harmful edits to popular posts to earn a portion of it's rep gain.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If you think you've come up with a solution to those types of problems that would enable collaboratively edited posts that do a good job of distributing the rep based on the actual value of each contribution (or even a reasonable approximation) and that doesn't encourage abusive or harmful edits, by all means, make a feature request for it (after familiarizing yourself with past attempts and past suggestions to ensure your suggestion is novel).

Comment: I don't think such a system could be fully automated as long as there is *generally* a single score for reputation that works by summing points for actions. It would need input from reviewers. I do remember the Documentation feature. I remember thinking it was a brilliant concept. I **don't** remember thinking about reputation gains from it, in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 6):

I think it depends on whether you authored the question/answer from scratch, and if a different canonical (one that was posted by someone else) already exists.

The ethical concern is that you are using your place in the community to create a situation in which reputation is funneled to your question rather than somewhere else.

If a user who does not participate in chat and the canonical projects posted a question on the topic, why should it not be them who gets 10k rep over the next year from that, rather than you? Since it is you who is making the decision on which question is the winner and which is the loser, and you will be choosing your own work, it introduces a conflict of interest.

CW is a tool to mitigate the conflict of interest. If your goal is fully altruistic and you indeed don't care about reputation gain, why does it matter either way? Easy to check the CW box and just shut down the discussion before it even begins. That you resist doing so opens the door to questioning your motives.

As active answerers in the tag are working through questions, if the choice to select your canonical means rep for you rather than them, it creates an incentive to simply answer instead of closing as a dupe. Or an incentive for each active person making their own canonical that they use instead of the central, "global" one.

I am not passionate about it either way, but I certainly see the merit in the opposing view to yours. My conclusion is that canonicals should be CW for the sake of process.

Comment: Here's a scenario. I'm a very knowledgeable 2k user who actually cares about my rep. I want to contribute to the site and gain rep, that's what I came here to do. Why would I not be able to write a very good question/answer and get reputation for it? If many people edit a post, it may be worth considering. But how many canonicals are actually extensively edited by many people?

Comment: @SecondRikudo The flip side: I am an active 2k user who cares about my rep. I see a question and know about your canonical answer, but decide to write my own answer instead of just handing you the rep.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I expect you to do! [so] is a Q&A site where there can be multiple answers on a question and the best one is voted to the top. See my question about mysql_*, the second most voted question is one of the latest ones to be posted.

Comment: @SecondRikudo That defeats the purpose of dup cleanups and canonical answers. We're trying to build centralized points to close dups against.

Comment: Yes, and that means one question. Not necessarily one answer.

Comment: @SecondRikudo It has been my impression that coordinated efforts at establishing canonicals seek to create a single question/answer pair that addresses one specific topic exhaustively, against which all future duplicates can be closed. Creating any incentive to ignore that central question in favor of posting a new one is counter-productive to that aim.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Chris' example had the second answer provided to a duplicate question, instead of having it closed, not posting a new answer to a canonical question.  There is nothing wrong with multiple answers to a canonical question.

Comment: @Chris: I'll give the example of my mysql_* question again. You can get the main points from the top (accepted) answer, and see a more in-depth explanation in the subsequent answers. You can go to the point or actually take the time and read on the subject. Which I think is awesome.

Comment: @SecondRikudo That is not the same scenario. I am talking about a person coming to a new question. The choice is a) answer and get rep for myself, or b) close it and send more people at your questions, so you get the rep. If the canonical is CW, at least the "giving it away" part of the scenario is removed. It makes the "don't get the rep yourself" part easier to sell and swallow. NOT going CW sends a message: get rep. Okay, so why close a question when I can answer it?

Comment: @Chris: That's not what I said should happen. But you could answer the canonical with your improved version, it'll probably get more views and votes too. Also, regardless of whether I get the rep or not, you'll get the rep by answering the duplicate anyway (which in my opinion *is* a flaw in the system itself).

Comment: @SecondRikudo That's not the choice most users are put in though.  Most of these users are mediocre programmers and writers.  They aren't capable of writing a question better than the canonical question, but they *are* capable of writing a noticeably worse answer that some uniformed user asking a question about the subject will upvote, in isolation, if they didn't realize there was a canonical post with a *far* better answer already.  Thus these newer, less skilled programmers are given a choice.  Vote/flag to close as a duplicate of a post with a great answer, or post their own crappy one.

Comment: @Servy: In which case, regardless of the CW state of the canonical in question, they'll choose for themselves (generally post their crappy one).

Comment: @SecondRikudo Exactly, which is why canonical posts end up being not nearly as useful as they could be.  There's just so little incentive for anyone but the author of the canonical question to vote to close as a duplicate.  [This recent change](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers) might help though.  We'll see.  Tim also said more changes will be coming soon to how duplicates are handled.

Comment: @Servy For extremely common FAQ dups, if we could [Close against the tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253175/allow-tag-wiki-to-be-referenced-in-duplicate-close-vote) instead of having to shim the deficiencies of the tag wiki with answers, we would probably not even be having this conversation. Though, notably, no one would get rep from that either.