# What question should we link [excel-vba] last row duplicates to?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847522/make-the-vba-script-look-for-the-next-empty-row) gets asked by every new vba "programmer" out there. I always flag it as a dupe, but admittedly, it gets asked so often that I don't think I've marked it as the dupe of the same question twice. Do we have a canonical answer for this? Is it worth attempting to write one? It seems that [writing a new canonical answer is a hassle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254896/lets-not-strive-to-make-all-canonical-questions-a-pain-to-make).

Here's a (kind of sloppy) [search for potential Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bvba%5d%20%5bexcel-vba%5d%20is%3aquestion%20first%20empty%20row).

I think I personally gravitate to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056663/3198973).

With over 100 results in my search above, I hope we can agree that it's an issue we need to resolve. Hopefully we can also agree on a single Q&A to guide people to.

Ironic moment of the day. Someone just asked an [incredibly intelligent question on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848840/find-row-macro-clarification). This just might be a good candidate.

Answer (score 4):

I found a great [Q&A pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) for last row questions. This is my official nomination. I will be marking questions as a duplicate of this one from now on.

Comment: I can never find that Q although I've seen it before. I know Sid has a [post on his personal website](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/) which is even more detailed. I often just flag the Q and post a link to that reference.  But this is a good find. I will have to try and remember it :)

Comment: That's why I posted it here. I can never find it either. =;)-