# Delete a question that was used as a duplicate target

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

So this question pops up in the reopen queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322297/sql-language-tutorial

The question is highly off-topic, and the OP admits to it. Deletion seems to be the appropriate action, because it really doesn't serve much purpose since it's just a thread linking to other sites and all of the answers could be flagged low quality (two answers link to the same W3Schools page). There are already two delete votes, so I clicked to vote for deletion and...

> This question cannot be deleted because other questions are linked as duplicates of this one. 
>   
>   Those posts must be deleted - or reopened, if they are not truly duplicates - before this question can be deleted.

Ok... So what's marked as a duplicate of this? There's a handy link to them, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2322297?lq=1

So it's a laundry list of mostly poor questions that generally point back to this question as a "Please learn SQL" statement. I only count four that count this question as a duplicate of them and none of them are asking for an SQL tutorial. Of those four, three could be deleted and the other is an [otherwise decent question that should be reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784484/cant-get-sql-join-to-work-properly). The rest are either [poor questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085/looking-for-a-very-basic-introduction-to-sql) or failed attempts to mark it as a duplicate.

Is this something for only moderators to handle? I wasn't sure where to even begin in trying to flag this since it covers so many threads.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a little off of your headline's subject, but there's a broader issue to consider before you delete the master question here.

I've [come to the conclusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252861/159251) that having one good, curated, up-to-date instance of these "lists of tutorials/resources" questions per major tag is probably a good idea unless and until [tag wikis become more versatile as information repositories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122226/) or even [usable as dupe masters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253175/allow-tag-wiki-to-be-referenced-in-duplicate-close-vote).

People are going to keep asking for resource links; it's easier to have a place to point them at, especially with the existence of [the dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/159251). I don't know if this question you've brought up is the canonical one for SQL, but I'd suggest keeping it and trying to improve it to that state if there isn't one. (Or start from a better one, if such exists.)

(Moderators have generally been willing, in my experience, to finish the cleanup -- deleting all but the best one or two answers, applying a ["wiki answer" lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading/182572#182572) -- once the majority has been done.)

Having taken that into consideration, however, if this one still isn't worth saving, then by all means ask in chat or here on Meta for help. You can also flag for stuff that only a mod would be able to do. Just be as thorough and clear as you possibly can in the flag description.

Comment: I tend to agree to a certain extent. But I would say that that "curation honor" would be better served by [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519/learning-sql), which doesn't just link resources, but discusses them at length. The quality difference between this thread and the one in my OP is obvious.

Comment: Fair enough, @Machavity; in that case I'd say asking for assistance with this one is indeed appropriate. Since the closed linked questions are slam dunks for deletion/reopening, you should be able to get ready help from other users, but you can certainly flag if necessary.