# Questions closed for recommending/finding an off-site resource should be deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, recommendation-questions

When searching for a library/tool/... with my favourite search engine, there are often results from Stack Overflow. Since these questions are (in theory) closed and/or outdated, they pollute my search results and cause annoyance.

First I thought these questions shouldn't appear in my search engine in the first place, but the team [has explained why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316904/247702) they don't want to do that.

> We want to show Google the same thing we show everyone else. Since closed questions are still visible on the site, they're visible to Google. *Deleted* questions are hidden for most users (only visible at 10k+ rep) and are therefore not indexed by Google.

The team also comments:

> Of course, this raises the question of whether we should be *deleting* all those old closed questions, but that seems like it should be a separate question.

While outright deleting all those closed questions may be a step too far, I argue that at least those questions closed for recommending/finding an off-site resource should be deleted. Whether this is done via an automated process or a coordinated community effort, is up for discussion, I'm fine with both.

In response to Hans' comment, we should also think about users who are less familiar with the site, e.g. those who end up ranting on the internet about SO, or those who simply view SO as just another website appearing in search results. They may not know or may not be interested in filtering search results, since it's an extra step required.

Comment: The vast majority *do* get deleted, in my experience.  It's pretty rare for them not to.  Anyway, are you suggesting that users be more free with their delete votes on questions like these, that all questions closed for this reason be automatically deleted, or something else?

Comment: @Servy I prefer an automated process, but maybe a coordinated community effort is a better idea. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, you know that resource questions are off topic on SO.  So what would be the point in clicking *at all* when Google shows an SO search hit?  Just don't and you don't need this to have this gritty problem solved, deletion is too strongly inhibited to ever get this fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant I know that, yes, and I do tend to skip over them, but they still push other results further down. We should also consider people who are less familiar with the site, e.g. those who end up ranting on the internet about SO, or those who simply view SO as just another website appearing in search results.

Comment: There's a long discussion about deleting posts [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337098/why-dont-we-just-delete-crappy-questions)

Comment: @Stijn Having recently seen someone arguing that any Stack Overflow post that ranks highly in a programming-related Google query is automatically on-topic here, I sympathise with the concern about ranting users. However, I am not sure we can do much about them, as they seem to be affected by a fundamental failure to grasp what community curation is.

Comment: Potential close voters: this is *obviously* not a duplicate of the question MD XF linked to. "We should delete all bad questions" is not at all equivalent to "we should delete all closed recommendation questions".

Comment: if you need to exclude some google seach results from SO, append `-site:stackoverflow.com` to search query. why do you think questions are outdated? it is unlikely. some answers may be obsolete, but other are still useful

Comment: The argument from the perspective of Google is a good one actually. Usually the focus is on making questions easier to find, but the other way around is just as important when it comes to not selling Stackoverflow as something it is not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Most* of these are deleted. There's a close reason for it, hundreds of questions do get closed for that reason, and most closed questions do get deleted...

For this specific close reason, 22 closed questions were deleted in the past day; 23788 questions in the past year, and 81455 questions for all-time. That's out of a total of 102928 questions that've been closed for that particular reason (or one of the 3 previous variations on it), putting the deletion rate at just shy of 80%.

Of course, that also leaves 21 thousand such questions still hanging around. Just shy of 400 will be deleted automatically soon anyway; another 900 or so are unanswered but themselves score > 0 - we could probably delete those without any qualms too.

However... 17 thousand or so are answered; that is, they either have an upvoted answer or an accepted answer - about 14 thousand have both. Not quite 7 thousand are upvoted, answered, *and* have an accepted answer. These are the questions we probably *wouldn't* want to automate deletion of... And it's still a pretty good pile of questions; we'd have to make a little event of it.

Which raises the question... What, if anything, is worth saving here? And how do we go about saving it? We've had a site *dedicated* to Software Recommendations for a couple of years now, with [a well-defined process](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) for asking these questions constructively; I'm not suggesting we should be migrating anything off of Stack Overflow, but perhaps if there are well-defined questions we could just keep them around? Stuff that's trying to solve a real problem and just happens to be phrased as a resource-request... No sense in reviewing these if we're not gonna try & do something with the ones we *don't* delete.

Sounds like a lot of work in any case, but if folks are up for it I'll build a list of the questions.

**Update:** [here is such a list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run), albeit a short one

Comment: Just for reference, if a list does end up being worked on, we'd likely want to start with questions with lower views, lower votes, questions that don't have much recent activity, and that are older (not sure how all of those factors should be weighted though).  Those would be the least likely to still have useful information in them, and would therefore be most likely to be worth the time to review for deletion.

Comment: Looks like voting has stalled, with +30/-10. How should we proceed? I assume I'm able to build the list myself with the data explorer, but if it's not too much work for you to build the list, feel free to do so.

Comment: [Let's give this a trial run](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341987/lets-rescue-wayward-resource-requests-trial-run), @Stijn

Answer (score 6):

These questions do get deleted as they come to the attention of users with the power to delete or delete-vote, with the exception of one or two major canonical resource posts that have garnered hundreds or thousands of votes and remain updated by one or two persevering users. I can't recall which ones those are off the top of my head, but there's probably a C++ one and maybe a JavaScript one.

As a 10k+ user, you have the ability to cast delete votes on these questions, which will put them in the queue for other 10k users to delete. Additionally, if you feel it's worth the trouble, or think the question is *harmful* if it remains around, you can flag the question for a moderator to take a look at it.

*If* you want to rely on the assumption that no results from Stack Overflow will be useful in your searches (based on past experience or any other reason), you can always add the following modifier to the end of your search query in Google:

`-site:stackoverflow.com`

Ex: `"List of C++ tutorials -site:stackoverflow.com"`

This should remove any results from the `stackoverflow.com` domain from your results list.

---

If you want to start a community-coordinated process, I would recommend looking at the (current) community process for tag burnination that was spearheaded by the SOCVR chatroom and is now implemented; it could provide a good starting template.

Comment: I'll probably head over to the chat room at some point to see how this can be coordinated. The first step (and goal of this question) is to see whether the community agrees with deletion.

Comment: Yeah C++ maintains a list of good programming books.  It gets used **a lot**

Comment: @Stijn I agree with deleting all off-site resource posts, personally.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but does potentially help solve your initial problem.

Search engines usually allow you to provide filters to your results, one of these being dates.  I usually search posts from the last year when current information would be more valuable.
[image: Selecting a time filter from the search options.]

Answer (score 0):

Independent from whether this should happen or not, I vote against doing it in an automated way.

Some of those questions have proven to be useful. It's a problem that they are questions and answers, which the content is not well suited for. Instead they probably should have been included in the relevant tag wikis.

Before deletion happens (if any) the content should be checked if it's a useful resource and preserved in some way like in a tag wiki. There's also this SO Docs thing which nobody really knows what it's about, maybe this kind of content could find a home there.

Either way, an automated deletion process would possibly do more harm than it would help.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  The legacy stuff would likely not need to be touched, and the new questions asking for resources *should* be shut down as quickly as possible to prevent people from thinking that these kinds of questions are okay.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this, with the exception that each "tag community" [should be allowed to keep one good, *maintained*, canonical resources post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299319/603977). (The question part of such a post should likely be locked, which I think is fine, although it would be nice if certain [trusted but non-diamond users could still work with them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252861/159251).)

"What book should I read to learn [tag]?" questions are never going to stop coming, and the best way to deal with them is to speedily close them as duplicates of a canonical list.

These lists would of course fit better in tag wikis than questions, [but the wikis can't be used as dupe targets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122226/159251).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of those questions and have no intention of deleting them :)