# Clicking on "Add Info" takes me to the Express Interest 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, 404-not-found

I can't reproduce this, but here's a description as best as I can make it:

The first-time help popup tooltip thing on the Express Interest button on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/196567/developers-python-javascript-react-wanted-to-unipart-group) job had a button that said "Add Info". I didn't actually want to apply to the job, but I wanted to fill out information so I clicked on it.

It took me to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/express-interest/196567), which appears to me as a 404. The actual button proper didn't even take me there; it took me to a page allowing me to fill in my Developer Story information. This is strange, unexpected, and probably a bug.

Comment: We'll take a look, thanks! That page (/jobs/express-interest/196567) 404s because it expects a POST, not a GET.

Comment: Wow look at that! The developers *can* make changes, even if the request wasn’t posted on Twitter!

Comment: @Tim Yeah, yeah, we get it. Also, your sarcasm is a little undermined by the size of [status-completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+-tags+-tag-synonyms+-tag-wiki+-tag-disambiguation+-tag-badges+-tag-search+-tag-creation+-tag-score+-tag-excerpt+-tag-tips+-tag-alias-request+-tag-watching+-tag-blacklist+-tag-hierarchy+-tag-dropdown+-tag-autocomplete).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that doesn’t pale in comparison to the ones they’ve [completely ignored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-bug+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-planned+-status-deferred+-status-review+-status-reproduced) at all does it!?

Comment: @Tim [Here are the ones they've "ignored" that aren't duplicates and that have a non-negative score.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+-%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D+-%5Bstatus-declined%5D+-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+-%5Bstatus-planned%5D+-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+-%5Bstatus-review%5D+-%5Bstatus-reproduced%5D+duplicate%3Ano+score%3A0%2B). But that includes questions like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253175/allow-tag-wiki-to-be-referenced-in-duplicate-close-vote), where people have argued against.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no, that’s with a score of exactly 0... [here’s ignored with a positive score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+score%3A0..+-%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D) - there’s 8076 of them, not 78. And sure, we can argue about the actual number which people want, but I have better things to do than look through all of them. I think it’s pretty safe to say that they ignore more than they answer. Anyway, I’m glad they answered this promptly. I’m angry they’ve ignored almost all of mine, ones which impact their core users...

Comment: @Tim I'd have to do a better analysis than just searching (which I've concluded to be flawed, despite initially bring it up) in order to reach a conclusion about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

The default click handler of the `<a>` element was run, as we forgot to disable it. The fix was a one-liner `return false;`.